# How to Switch from a login screen (without the navigationdrawer layout) to a screen with a navigationdrawer layout python/kivy/kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am relatively new to app development and I am attempting to create a login screen that, if successfully logged into, takes you to a "dashboard" screen that has the layout of NavigationDrawer.

I attempted to leverage what I found on Git hub here: https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/wiki/Components-Navigation-Drawer

I was thinking it would be as "easy" as taking what is at that URL and creating a screen with the NavigationDrawer disabled, but have been pretty unsuccessful in find a solution.

Any ideas or help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button at the end of your login screen like `let's go` or `continue` or whatever. Then you can bind an on-press action to that which change the screen to your home screen. To change screen you have to do so using a `screen_manager`. Make sure all of your screens are inside it. Then to change to a particular screen just use `screen_manager.current = screen_id`.

Comment: But if I’m using NavigationDrawer which... if following the example in the link... would mean you have your Screen Manager imbedded in your NavigationLayout and therefore you’d have your NavigationDrawer (what pops up on the left side with the different menu items) on that said login screen which is what I’m trying to resolve? Maybe I’m missing what you’re recommending?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solved it by simply adding `self.root.ids['screen_manager'].current= 'screen_id'` just after the user is successfully logged.